Why are open sets Carathéodory measurable?
I know that open sets are Lebesgue measurable(By the definition of Lebesgue measurability) and that Lebesgue measurable means Carathéodory measurable. This means Open sets are Carathéodory measurable. But I want to know is there any way of proving this directly without using the equivalence of the two definitions. FYI: A set $E$ of a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M},\mu)$ is Carathéodory measurable if there is for every $A \subset X$ we have $\mu(A) = \mu(A \cap E) + \mu(A \cap E^{c})$.
